# Java: reading Xml configuration and applying to an object, what's a lightweight, simple solution

Tags: java, configuration, jaxb

In our various applications, we have a hodge-podge of different methods used to read Xml configuration info and apply it to a Java object.

I am looking for a utility that, when given some Xml element, will automatically take any  child element and set a corresponding property on the object to be configured (and of course handle any data conversion from String to correct standard Java data type).

I realize I am describing something a lot like JAXB (which I've used only a little, as part of a project to serialize/deserialize objects to Xml), so maybe it's the best solution?  I just don't particularly want to be required to add the annotations to the class, and would rather it be assumed that any setter corresponds to any similarly named Xml element.

Any recommendations on what should be a standard way to do this would be appreciated.  (And I'm fine if people say go back and read the JAXB docs, because that's the best solution.)

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**  I did end up with JAXB, although it wasn't exactly painless. The main downside is that it is not case-insensitive (when you are dealing with config files, it's best not to require match by case). One other downsides are that you need to deploy 3 additional jars.  I ended up with this code (maybe there is something more elegant):

```
public class JAXBConfigurator<T> {

private String filePath;
private Class<T> clazz;
public JAXBConfigurator(Class<T> toConfigure, String xmlFilePath) {
    this.clazz = toConfigure;
    this.filePath = xmlFilePath;
}

/**
 * @return Parses Xml and reads configuration from Document element. Using this method assumes that the
 * configuration xml starts at the top of the xml document.
 * @throws Exception
 */
public T createAndConfigure() throws Exception {
    return createAndConfigure(null);
}

/**
 * Selects specified element from the parsed Xml document to use as the base
 * for reading the configuration.
 * 
 * @param tagName
 * @return
 */
public T createAndConfigure(String tagName) throws Exception {
    Document doc = XmlUtils.parse(filePath);
    Node startNode;
    if (tagName == null) {
        startNode = doc;
    } else {
        startNode = XmlUtils.findFirstElement(doc, tagName);
    }

    return readConfigFromNode(startNode);
}

private T readConfigFromNode(Node startNode) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    JAXBElement<T> configElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(startNode, clazz);
    return configElement.getValue();
}
```

}

The class gets used like this:

```
JAXBConfigurator<MyConfig> configurator = new JAXBConfigurator<Config>(MyConfig.class, xmlfilePath);
instance = configurator.createAndConfigure("MyXmlStartTag");
```

...which seems reusable enough for most scenarios.  Thanks again to everyone who responded.

Comment: Which additional jar files did you need to deploy?  A JAXB implementation is included with every implementation of Java SE 6.  You would need jars if using JDK 1.5 or another JAXB implementation such as EclipseLink MOXy.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan: I didn't realize that JAXB was included in Java 6.  I was just following the docs on the JAXB site, [JAXB FAQ](http://jaxb.java.net/faq/index.html#runtime_jars).  We are using Java 6 everywhere, so I can test running without the jars.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JAXB (JSR-222) is configuration by exception.  This means that no annotations are required.  You just need to add metadata to override the default rules:

**For an Example**

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/TheBasics

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, and pointer that no annotations are required. JAXB leaves something to be desired for this application (case-sensitivity for example), but was pretty nice for default solution. I wasn't able to figure how to use an Annotation to tell JAXB to select the Root element, so I ended up doing it with code. Probably there's a way, but I ran out of time.

Comment: @SamGoldberg - You may find the following article helpful for using JAXB to unmarshal case insensitive XML:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/case-insensitive-unmarshalling.html

Answer (score 2):

Pick one of these: Castor, XMLBeans, JiBX, XStream and JAXB. I'd recommend JAXB or JiBX. And in case you use Spring for other purpose, you can also check out [Spring Object/XML mapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/oxm.html), which is basically a wrapper around aforementioned implementations and provides a consistent API.

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestions.  I briefly started to look at Castor and XMLBeans, but given that your recommendation was JAXB and also so was Blaise's I decided to go that route. JAXB leaves something to be desired as a config reading tool, but it's not bad.